# FluentAssertions.Analyzers Not Providing Expected Suggestions or Messages

Tags: c#, .net, xunit, analyzer, fluent-assertions

I have a simple C# .NET 6 Xunit test project and am using `FluentAssertions` to verify the expected outcomes of my tests. I've been trying to use `FluentAssertions.Analyzers` to analyze these assertions.

However, the following test doesn't trigger any suggestions or yield error/warning/info messages, even though it should. What steps should I take to make the analyzer work?

```
public class UnitTest1
{
    [Fact]
    public void Test1()
    {
        var blah = true;
        blah.Should().Be(true);
    }
}
```

This is the .csproj file of the project:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>

    <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
    <IsTestProject>true</IsTestProject>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="FluentAssertions" Version="6.11.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="FluentAssertions.Analyzers" Version="0.21.0">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="17.5.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="xunit" Version="2.4.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="xunit.runner.visualstudio" Version="2.4.5">
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="coverlet.collector" Version="3.2.0">
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```